# iPhone: how to circumvent SSL no certificate while using local environment

Tags: iphone, ssl

I'm currently using my iPhone to connect to my local environment on my Macbook.  The part that won't work is that my local MUST be https, but its certificate is invalid.  Because of this, the phone refuses to load pretty much all of the page.  Does anyone know how to circumvent this?  I have searched and do not find any settings on iPhone to get around it.
To add to this, here's how I'm connecting:  iPhone plugged into Macbook via usb.  Both connected to same wifi.  In Safari, I type in https://[IP Address of my machine]:[port for server].

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question.  I deleted my answer

Comment: I think what you are asking for is addressed here https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/